# Arcpad, arcpy, checkout/in data and limiting to selected features

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

am working on developing a python toolbox to automate the steps required for checking data out and back into a file geodatabase. My question is what is the best way to limit the features checked out to only those selected while using the python command line and ArcPad Data Management tools instead of the ArcPad data manager? The "Only get selected features" checkbox in the ArcPad Data Manager makes it easy. This is important because I want to limit the areas of use and reduce the file size as one of the feature classes is a large parcel map.

Answer (score 0):

I do know one way to get selected items by using arcpy only.

```
    #get an map object
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    #get an dataframe object, here the first one is taken
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    #get a layer object
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"NameOfRequiredLayer",df)
    #now get the FIDs of the selected Elements of your layer
    selection = arcpy.Describe(lyr).FIDSet
```

"selection" then contains the FIDs of selected elements. With that you can carry one with whatever you have to do. For instance you can then set a layers definition query:

```
    #shapes use FID, feature classes use OBJECTID, so you better check
    IDname = "\"OBJECTID\""
    if lyr.dataSource.endswith("shp"):
        IDname = "\"FID\""
    querystring = IDname + " = " + str(selection[0])
    for count in range(1,len(selection)):
        querystring = querystring + " OR " + IDname + " = " + str(selection[count])   
    if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
        lyr.definitionQuery = querystring
```